# Configuring UPnP on pfSense

Tags: routing, port-forwarding, pfsense, upnp

I need a little help configuring UPnP on pfSense. I have installed pfSense between ADSL connection and connecting internal router.
  There are two video servers behind the router that need port 80, 81, 34567, and 34568 opened. I have NAT rules configured as so in
[image: Firewall: Nat: Port Forward]
and UPnP is configured so
[image: UPnP Settings]
where the interface is assumed to be facing the internal hosts 192.168/16, correct?
  I have no problem doing a telnet to the said port, but I'm not seeing any UPnP entries when I try to connect. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not supposed to use UPnP when you know what ports to forward. UPnP is used for dynamic (home) stuff to enable better connectivity for certain protocols (video, torrent and so on).

Just disable UPnP and use the first port forwarding rules. Just make sure that the firewall accept the packets (NAT rules are not firewall rules).